# How to create multiple text files each with different names using a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, text-files

I would like to create multiple empty text files each with a different name from a list of 70+ names, all within the same folder.

**Ex:** cat, dog, computer, tree.

**To output to:**

cat.txt

dog.txt

computer.txt

tree.txt

Comment: this is not a coding service. write some code, test it out. if it does not work, we will help you.

Comment: Sorry about that, I only have experience with front end web developement and after a long Google search I still couldn't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (list.txt) do break>%%a.txt
```

Comment: If you want a CR/LF (0xd,0xa) in the "empty" file replace the "**break**" with "**echo.**"